# Extend a class from dll

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dll

I have a third party DLL (which I can't edit) that has a class with code I would like to extend:

```
  namespace namespaceName
  {
     public class mainClass
     {
        public class className
        {
            public string string1;
            public string string2;
            public string string3;
            public string string4;
            public className(string string1, string string2, string string3, string string4);
        }
     }
 }
```

What I would like is the ability to add another string to the class className.

Can it be done using inheritance (if at all)?

Comment: I don't get the question... Of course you can do this. Just inherit it and use that type instead o.O

Comment: The only obvious thing you could do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard - What happens if the 3rd party class is `sealed`? :)

Comment: Then you can't ^.^ Not unless you can access the code and rewrite it.
Sealed is kinda there to prevent exactly this. Inheriting it x)

Comment: If you do not have access to the code and the class is sealed, you can always decompile the DLL and edit it: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: (Assuming it is legal.) Not suggesting anything anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from it and create your own class (unless it is sealed):

```
class ClassName2 : ClassName
{
  public string AnotherString { get; set; }
}
```